# SSD & HDD can't be detected by Windows 10 USB installler but Ubuntu works perfectly

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows, ssd

I partitioned space in my SSD to install Ubuntu and while trying to partition HDD to use it as home directory, I messed up and partitioned the SSD instead.
That lead to deletion of my Windows system files.
Now I'm trying to install windows back again by unallocating accidentally allocated space in SSD using live stick.
But, I don't see my drives (both SSD and HDD) on the partition phase of Windows installation.
Please note that I've got unallocated free-space on both of my SSD and HDD. HDD is not accessible via Ubuntu due to bitlock.
I tried running gparted but it doesn't detect my drives either. Help would be appreciated.

[Installer not detecting my drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpi4o.jpg)

Please note that I can easily boot into my Ubuntu so there might be no physical issue with the drives themselves.

Comment: Unlike Linux distros, Windows strictly requires MBR for Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode and GPT for UEFI mode. Make sure you're booting in the correct/intended mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:
All I needed was a media driver from Intel Rapid Speed Technology. I downloaded it from the official site that matched by machine's architecture and I loaded it to the same USB stick that I was using to install Windows. At the point where the installer asks to browse for the drives, all I did was browsed to my USB and selected the media driver. After that installer recognized all of my drives.

Comment: +1+1; Thanks for sharing your solution. It can be useful for other people who are dual booting Ubuntu and Windows :-) Looking forward I suggest that you set up a **backup** routine so that you will be able to recover easier from similar accidents.